# Facing an Error 'Could not Connect To Servers' while activating Test Complete10

Tags: testcomplete

I am installing Test Complete10 on my pc. I am facing an error

> Connection to the SmartBear Licence servers failed. Error: Connection with Sever Could not be established

I am using 'Automatic' Activate Licence and selected no proxy for internet connection. I see the support tutorials from softbear but it does not solve the issue . Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have two link only answers that are likely to get deleted by the review system.  It seems like you are being recommended to visit http://support.smartbear.com and either look at the troubleshooter or raise a ticket via their message system (append `/message/?prod=TestComplete` to the url).  I have no expertise here, just putting it in a comment to give you chance to see it as the link only answers are likely to be deleted pretty quick...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Licensing Troubleshooter:

http://support.smartbear.com/troubleshooter/?prod=Licensing